# How to reduce the image height in carousel slider

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to reduce the image height in carousel slide in bootstrap, but it must be responsive after reducing the image height.

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="images/xactprofile1.png" class="d-block w-100 d-inline-block" alt="..." />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It changes height when you try to reduce the height based on this. Add it to your image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src="img_chania.jpg" width="460" height="345">
<p>Resize the browser window to see how the image will scale.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works but the problem is it does not look good in responsive (inspect).

Comment: so change the height and width of the image @mohammednabil

Comment: I am referring to screen resolution in mobile device it looks very stretch.

Comment: try taking an image of good quality and set height accordingly @mohammednabil

Answer (score 0):

Will changing the `.carousel-inner` height solve your problem? or it's not what you are looking for? because you could use for example `height: 50vh` and it will change the images too but the whole inner is effected with it. and images are going to stay responsive.

check out this snippet:

CSS:

```css
.carousel-inner {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="slider">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080 " class="d-block w-100 vh-100" alt="pic-1">
        <div class="overlay "> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1081" class="d-block w-100 vh-100 " alt="pic-2">
        <div class="overlay "> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1082" class="d-block w-100 vh-100 " alt="pic-3">
        <div class="overlay "> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1083" class="d-block w-100 vh-100 " alt="pic-4">
        <div class="overlay "> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1084" class="d-block w-100 vh-100 " alt="pic-5">
        <div class="overlay "> </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```